# What does the style of favicons of Stack Exchange sites represent?

Tags: discussion, design, user-interface, favicon

I have noticed that there are different styles associated with [favicons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) of Stack Exchange sites.

Some sites have distinct graphical icons, with their respective metas having the grayed out version of the icon. E.g.: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/), [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), and [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).

[image: Icons of Stack Overflow, Mathematics, Ask Ubuntu, and Ask Different]

Other sites have sky-blue callout icons. Of these, for some sites the content of the callout is an abbreviation for the site. For others, it's again a graphical icon. And their respective metas have the same icon, but the callout's color is black. E.g.: [Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/), [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), [Aviation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/), and [Chess](https://chess.stackexchange.com/).

[image]

What do these different icon styles represent?

Comment: Note: I have a rough idea, but including that would have made the question opinion based.

Comment: The blue ones are beta sites and putting what you think already in the question does not make your question opinion based.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because designers, that's why.

Beta sites are given a *temporary* icon, consisting of characters or small icon representing the site name or topic, on a blue speech balloon modelled on the Stack Exchange logo. Pictograms are used where one is available (like for [Chess SE](https://chess.stackexchange.com/), the rook is an obvious choice), a one- or two-letter abbreviation otherwise. The [Craft CMS SE site](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/) got the same shape in red with a `C` in the same font as the typical branding for that CMS instead of a pictogram, presumably because a plain `C` on blue could have meant anything.

When a site graduates from public beta to full release, it is given a full-on unique design, which includes a site logo. A Stack Exchange designer first proposes a design on the site's Meta, and the final design is then created based on the community feedback. See the [Mathematics design proposal](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/963/design-ideas-for-mathematics-site) for example, where Jin briefly explains how he picked the logo.

Comment: Except that Craft got a red icon instead of blue... For reasons, I suppose.

Comment: @Thursday: The font is also different from usual; the red and the font choice act like a pictogram choice (e.g. they are the same kind of choice as using a rook for Chess). See the [Craft CMS homepage](https://buildwithcraft.com/).